# How to download 12.04 with resume option?

Tags: 12.04, downloads, bittorrent

I would like to download latest ubuntu 12.04 LTS. But, I have a lousy connectivity. Is there torrent-like download available which I can pause and resume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the bittorrent download as you said, the links are on this page:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 4):

Yes. All Ubuntu releases are distributed via bittorrent for those who prefer that to traditional direct downloads. Torrent release links are listed on the [Alternative Downloads page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) of the main Ubuntu site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wget` to do that:

```
wget -c http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso
```

After you lose the network just run it again in the same directory.